# How can this Ambient Context become null?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, static, abstract-class

Can anyone help me explain how `TimeProvider.Current` can become null in the following class?

```
public abstract class TimeProvider
{
    private static TimeProvider current =
        DefaultTimeProvider.Instance;

    public static TimeProvider Current
    {
        get { return TimeProvider.current; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
            }
            TimeProvider.current = value;
        }
    }

    public abstract DateTime UtcNow { get; }

    public static void ResetToDefault()
    {
        TimeProvider.current = DefaultTimeProvider.Instance;
    }
}
```

**Observations**

- All unit tests that directly reference TimeProvider also invokes ResetToDefault() in their Fixture Teardown.
- There is *no* multithreaded code involved.
- Once in a while, one of the unit tests fail because `TimeProvider.Current` is null (NullReferenceException is thrown).
- This only happens when I run the entire suite, but not when I just run a single unit test, suggesting to me that there is some subtle test interdependence going on.
- It happens approximately once every five or six test runs.
- When a failure occurs, it seems to be occuring in the first executed tests that involves `TimeProvider.Current`.
- More than one test can fail, but only one fails in a given test run.

FWIW, here's the DefaultTimeProvider class as well:

```
public class DefaultTimeProvider : TimeProvider
{
    private readonly static DefaultTimeProvider instance =
        new DefaultTimeProvider();

    private DefaultTimeProvider() { }

    public override DateTime UtcNow
    {
        get { return DateTime.UtcNow; }
    }

    public static DefaultTimeProvider Instance
    {
        get { return DefaultTimeProvider.instance; }
    }
}
```

I suspect that there's some subtle interplay going on with static initialization where the runtime is actually allowed to access `TimeProvider.Current` before all static initialization has finished, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Any help is appreciated.

---

FWIW I just threw

```
Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
```

in the getter, and it consistently reports the same ID for all test cases in a test run, so the issue seems not related to threading.

Comment: Does it happen too if you use a static constructor instead of static field initialization? On the DefaultTimeProvider that is.

Comment: I put this on my blog, as I was having some problems finding details of Ambient Context - hope you don't mind: http://relentlessdevelopment.wordpress.com/2013/09/30/testing-datetimes-and-other-things-with-an-ambient-context/

Comment: I've experienced something similar with MVVM framework **Caliburn.Micro** and its extension library **Caliburn.Micro.Contrib**. With this [original code] (http://pastebin.com/0eydNkEQ) from the extension library, I couldn't run my WPF application outside of Visual Studio (but I could debug the app just fine). As far as I remember, I got Stack Overflow exception, because **_baseTransformName** field was assigned with the **FallbackNameTransform** method and that method was called by the framework via **ViewLocator.TransformName**. I had to use [this workaround] (http://pastebin.com/Z4hVLzUm).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based solely on this code, `Current` could be `null` based on it being set to `null`.  This obviously isn't helpful to you.

Could you provide the code for the tests?  If there's a test interdependence, it would be helpful for readers in order to provide any feedback.

In the mean time, possibly Jon Skeet's article on singletons might be helpful, since `DefaultTimeProvider` is effectively acting as a singleton: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: I can't dump 113 xUnit.net tests here, and if there's a test interdependence, I can't figure out which one causes it.

Comment: xUnit, can you easily convert them to VS unit tests and run them in the VS unit test runner to see if there's a difference?  Maybe the R# test runner would be easier?  That would tell you if it's a side-effect of the runner.

Otherwise, I would throw some tracing output in there (especially in DefaultTimeProvider.get_Instance) to see where it's null in relation to other operations.

Comment: I think you are up to something, because I just converted *from* MSTest, and didn't have the problem before. However, there's no issue with xUnit.net's own GUI runner, so the problem may be with TestDriven.net. I'll follow up with Jamie.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer. Not that it completely explains what's going on, but the link provided at least teached my sometihing about static initialization I didn't know before (see my own answer on this page for more information).

Answer (score 6):

I may have a partial answer to this, thanks to the links provided by Peter Ritchie, although I can't fully explain what's going on. It would seem that there was some kind of race going on between static initilization of TimeProvider and DefaultTimeProvider. It may have to do with [beforefieldinit](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/beforefieldinit.html).

Changing the implementation seems to have resolved the issue. If not, it has certainly made the race condition much rarer, to a point where I have yet to see it.

I changed initialization of TimeProvider to this:

```
public abstract class TimeProvider
{
    private static TimeProvider current;

    static TimeProvider()
    {
        TimeProvider.current = new DefaultTimeProvider();
    }

    //...
}
```

And DefaultTimeProvider simply to this:

```
public class DefaultTimeProvider : TimeProvider
{
    public override DateTime UtcNow
    {
        get { return DateTime.UtcNow; }
    }
}
```

There is now only one static initializer in play (TimeProvider) and since it's an explicit static constructor the class is not marked beforefieldinit.

This seems to have done the trick...